# how to use multiple images ⁉

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

stamping one image worked just fine

but I need to stamp multiple images.

and this what made up :

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFilter, ImageTk
import random

mylist = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"]
randomnames = ['11','22','33','44','55','66','77','88','99']

background = Image.open('1.jpg')
foreground = Image.open('stamp.png')

for imagesss in mylist:
    Image.open(imagesss)
    background.paste(foreground, (0, 0), foreground)
    background.save(random.choice(randomnames)+'.jpg', quality=95)
```

the result of this code was stamping the same image (1.jpg) 3 times and save them with random names of randomnames list but what I really need is when I add images in IM folder then run the program, it will stamp all images and save them with the same names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a new background image, you have to store the image you open.  And if you want to replace the file, then use the same file name.

```
for imagesss in mylist:
    background = Image.open(imagesss)
    background.paste(foreground, (0, 0), foreground)
    background.save(imagesss, quality=95)
```